# How to add a custom class that extends View to Main Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have problems with adding a custom class to my Main Activity.

code in my custom class:

```
public class DetailView extends View {

    public DetailView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00 );



    }
}
```

code in main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText("hello");
    txt.setId(6);
    txt.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.addView(txt);

    DetailView detailView = new DetailView(this.getApplicationContext());
    linearLayout.addView(detailView);

}
```

Why can't is see the detailView? 
Im new to android development so I need any help I can get, or some good links or anything. Thanks

Comment: I think you didn't set height/ width of View

Comment: how do i set width and height?

Comment: Why don't you set this layout from XML?

Comment: I have this in my main.xml but im just really confused about the xml stuff? Do i need to set height/width if i have this in my XML?         <com.example.test.DetailView
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view is added, but it has no dimension set. Looking at existing code I guess you want it do fill the width and have a small height - just assuming. So try the following:

```
DetailView detailView = new DetailView(this);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2); // 2 pixels height
linearLayout.addView(detailView, params);
```

Also, the context of the `DetailView` is the activity, not the application context.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, so I should change getApplicationContext() and get the context of main activity instead?

Comment: Yes, but you need to set the params as well.